# Single file upload

Tags: uploads, media, single, flash

I would like to allow user to only upload one file at a time using the flash uploader interface.
I found around here a link to a hack allowing to generate an error message when more than one file is selected but that's not what I want.
I would like to only take the first file into consideration and just ignore the other files.

Would it be possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can just grab the first file in the $_FILES array.

`if ($_FILES) {
return $FILES[0];
}`

Comment: Thank you Rachel, that seems nice. Can you tell me in which file I should put this?

Comment: I had a good look and I definitely don't know where to put this bit of code. I'm inside media.php and this doesn't fit anywhere I can think of. Thank you for your help

Comment: Where is your code to process the post results of your upload form?

Comment: I don't use any specific code.It's Wordpress native code so I believe it's "wp-includes/media.php". The hack I found is useless so I just got rid of it. Thank you Rachel